# Is it necessary/possible to specifically target foreign-language "editions" of amazon?

Tags: amazon, language

In addition to the original English, there are language-specific Amazon sites, such as, for Spanish, https://www.amazon.es/

I have created some bilingual books of works in the public domain, such as Robert Louis Stevenson's "Treasure Island" ("La Isla del Tesoro"), and am working on others.

These are intended for those who know one of the languages (English or Spanish) well, and who want to improve their skills in the other language. These books would possibly find more appeal among Spanish speakers looking to improve their English than vice versa.

Yet, my "Treasure Island" book does not seem to be available on https://www.amazon.es/ (the Spanish-language site).

Do I need to do something "special" when publishing these books via CreateSpace to ensure that they appear in the Spanish-language amazon site in addition to the English site?

### UPDATE

I was wrong; it is there after all ([here](https://www.amazon.es/Treasure-Island-Isla-del-Tesoro-ebook/dp/B00ZDJZH3S/)), but I still question its availability for all the Spanish speakers in Latin America (everything south of the U.S. all the way through Chile) because the currency displayed is Euros.

Why are the books on the https://www.amazon.es/ not also sold in Pesos and Bolivars and whatever other currencies are used in those countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon.es is amazon's website for Spain and not the Spanish language. Amazon has different websites based on a country (due to taxes, copyright, etc.) and not based on a language.

And I know that I cannot get access to ebooks in Spanish that are not in the US Amazon website if the author or the published didn't make it available here. So even though you can look at those other amazon.com  websites, you'll not be able to make any purchases.

So when searching a book in Spanish, I simply type the name of the book (either in Spanish or English) and add

> Spanish edition